# Use Socket IO In Node js to update pug template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, pug

In one of the projects I use Node Js / Express with Pug.js,I want to use socket io to make everything live,all post actions and bring information or update.

I tried to use socket io but all I managed to do was generate html code from js between 2 live users,
but i can't figure out how i can use io socket directly in api route / controllers to adapt pug template directly and angular app.
To prevent any damage to my app I built a controller and text routes.

1. **server.js**

   ```
   const app = require('./app');

   //Port
   const port = process.env.PORT || '7000';

   const server = app.listen(port,()=>{
     console.log(`Server Is Running!!!!`);
   });
   ```
2. **app.js**

   ```
    const express = require('express');
     .........
    //App Routes
    const viewRoutes = require('./routes/viewRoutes');
    const postRoutes = require('./routes/postRoutes');
   //Api Routes
   app.use('/api/v2/post',postRoutes);
   app.use('/',viewRoutes);


   module.exports = app;
   ```

4. **controllers/postController.js**

   ```
   /*import mongoose schema*/ 
   const Module = require('../module/testingModule');

   //Testing Purpose
   exports.createRandomText = catchAsync(async(req,res)=>{
    const test = await Module.create(req.body);
    console.log(req.body);

    res.status(200).json({
       status:'success',
       data:test
      })
   });
   ```
5. **routes/postRoutes.js**

   ```
    const postController = require('../controllers/postController');

    //Testing Purpose
    router.route('/test-create').post(postController.createRandomText);

    module.exports = router;
   ```
6. **view/testLive.pug**

   ```
   extends baseac 
   block content
      if(user)
          include header_footer/header_app
          .container
              form.testingPurpopseForm
                 .form-group
                    label(for="exampleInputRandomText") Random Text</label>
                     input(type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputRandomText" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Random Text")
                button(type="submit" class="btn btn-primary") Submit
           .container
              ul
                 each ts in test.reverse()
                    li=ts.randomText
   ```
7. **routes/viewsRoute.js**

   ```
   //TestingPurpose
    router.route('/test').get(authController.protect,viewsController.testLive);

    module.exports = router;
   ```
8. **views/viewsController.js**

   ```
   //Testing Purpose
   exports.testLive = catchAsync(async(req,res)=>{
        const getTextTest = await Module.find();
          res.status(200).render('./testLive',{
             test:getTextTest
          });
     });
   ```

In the oven I made the script by which I take the value from the formula from the pug template and I insert it in the database.

1. **public/js/main.js**

   ```
   document.querySelector('.testingPurpopseForm').addEventListener('submit',(dataTest)=>{
           dataTest.preventDefault();

         const random = document.getElementById('exampleInputRandomText').value;


         createRandomText(random);
    });
   ```
2. **public/js/testRandomCreate.js**

   ```
    import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
    import axios from 'axios';


    export const createRandomText  = async(dataRandom) =>{
        try{
            const rand = await axios({
               method:"POST",
               url:"/api/v2/post/test-create",
              data:{
                  randomText:dataRandom
              }
        });
        }catch(err){
           showAlert('error','There was a problem creating yout post!!!');
           console.log(err);
        }    
    }
   ```

[image]

I want when the user posts a random UI text to adapt instantly, I tried to understand the socket documentation I applied some examples from youtube but I create the elements from js and I don't adapt pug template unless I give refresh.

It is possible to use socket io in this example to adapt pug template and also the mobile application